# Closed form expression for scattering states in Hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, scattering

The self-adjointness of the Hamiltonian of the Hydrogen atom follows from the Kato-Rellich theorem, as is mentioned e.g. in Brian Hall's book. The eigenstates of $H$ corresponding to $E<0$, i.e. the bound states, have a closed form expression that is often given in physics textbooks. In Hall's book it is proven that these form a basis of the negative energy subspace of $L^2$, but not of all $L^2$. In case $E>0$, the spectrum is purely continuous, so there are no eigenstates of $H$ in $L^2$. I think in physics we call these states 'scattering states'. Does there exist a closed-form expression for these? My guess is that these would be distributions, and one could work out a Gelfand-triple for this system, but I haven't seen this approach at all. I would be interested in providing an eigenbasis of $H$ for the whole $L^2$ (or perhaps some larger space, say, dual of Schwartz). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, they are scattering states, and are solved in some rare texts, but only in the advanced portion, because they are incredibly much more complicated to deal with. The parts that do it justice would be the use of spherical waves, where the scattering just gives each partial wave a phase shift. Look up Coulomb wavefunctions. Yes, these will, just like momentum and position "eigen-(wave)-functions" be living in Rigged Hilbert space of your Gelfand triples, and thus also not be valid quantum states, but using them for basis expansion is still valid.